# winforms .Net Regarding use of small methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, inline

I work on developing application using winforms in C#. While developing, I want to use many small methods e.g. resetPerticularCombo(), so the code remains as clean as possible. But the problem is making methods for 3-5 lines of code could lead to too many method calls, I have heard that while compiling Visual Studio 2008 takes care of this thing using code inlining.

My query is that, should I rely on this feature and go ahead with the usage of small helper methods or I should use inlining myself?

Comment: If you're simply trying to avoid code clutter (full-blow methods for code used only from one function), you could make local `Action` or `Func` delegate instances, initialized with lambdas.  This won't be a performance improvement in any way (but see Jon Skeet's answer for why that doesn't matter), but it can sometimes make a readability gain, especially when you have repeated code.  E.g. `Action doSomething = c => c = a * (b + c);`, when you have to write the same line several times.  Then you'd just call `doSomething(g); doSomething(h);`.

Comment: Having methods which are 3-5 lines of code long sounds pretty good to me. In general I try to keep all of my methods smaller than 12 lines of code. If you have very large methods (even hundreds of lines long) it indicates a serious problem in your design...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about having large number of method calls until you've *proved* that it's a problem. It's very unlikely (IMO) that this will *actually* cause an issue, and if it gives you more readable code, that's the most important thing.

But *test* the performance all the time to see whether it's acceptable. Find out where the bottleneck in your code is, whether by profiling or other techniques, and consider micro-optimizing just at the points where it'll make the most difference.

In my experience micro-optimizing at the "use fewer methods" sort of level is almost always pointless compared with higher level changes (e.g. going from a list lookup to a dictionary lookup, etc).

Comment: I agree with finding the bottlenecks first - I recently discovered the joy of Stopwatch in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I agree to Jon Skeet.

Concerning Enterprise Applications I can tell you the following

I'm leading a small developer team ( 5 Developers) . We 've an application with about 500k loc.

We always try to find the most particular concern a method should have. So we got a lot of small, and "selfexplaining" methods.
As a result we have a many many methods and this never lead to an issue.

Most of the time the bottlenecks are in accessing ressources like SQL Server, Files, etc...
Or a lack of asynchronity.

Also i've you have a perfomance you could profile it using ants profilder.

I also like these "rules" of optimization I found sometime ago on the web

> FirstRuleOfOptimization - Don't.
>
> SecondRuleOfOptimization - Don't... yet. P
>
> ThirdRuleOfOptimization - ProfileBeforeOptimizing

If your developing a timecritical software (Graphic or driver related) then this things can make the point, but then I wouldn't be sure if .net were the best environment to do that

Comment: Thanks a lot Boas, espacially about Rules of Optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of small routines is fine, as other answers already say, but remember to consider refactoring similar routines, for readability and maintenance (and not specifically for performance).

`resetPerticularCombo()` and `resetAnotherCombo()` may be worth converting to `resetCombo(PerticularCombo)` and `resetCombo(AnotherCombo)`, if the routines are otherwise the same.

With anonymous lambdas, this can even be used to consolidate other similar algorithms: <sub>(potentailly bad example, but to continue using the OP's code)</sub> `ProcessCombo(PerticularCombo, (c)=>c.Reset())` and `ProcessCombo(PerticularCombo, (c)=>c.SelectFirst())`

<sub>I'm a VB.NET programmer and this code has been entered directly into SO without any syntax checking.</sub>